# Getting Home Directory with pathlib

Tags: python, python-3.4

Looking through the new `pathlib` module in Python 3.4, I notice that there isn't any simple way to get the user's home directory. The only way I can come up with for getting a user's home directory is to use the older `os.path` lib like so:

```
import pathlib
from os import path
p = pathlib.Path(path.expanduser("~"))
```

This seems clunky. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that this method was brought up in a bug report [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue19776). Some code was written (given [here](http://bugs.python.org/review/19776/patch/10200/38548)) but unfortunately it doesn't seem that it made it into the final Python 3.4 release.

Incidentally the code that was proposed was extremely similar to the code you have in your question:

```
# As a method of a Path object
def expanduser(self):
    """ Return a new path with expanded ~ and ~user constructs
    (as returned by os.path.expanduser)
    """
    return self.__class__(os.path.expanduser(str(self)))
```

#### EDIT

Here is a rudimentary subclassed version `PathTest` which subclasses `WindowsPath` (I'm on a Windows box but you could replace it with `PosixPath`). It adds a `classmethod` based on the code that was submitted in the bug report.

```
from pathlib import WindowsPath
import os.path

class PathTest(WindowsPath):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PathTest, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def expanduser(cls):
        """ Return a new path with expanded ~ and ~user constructs
        (as returned by os.path.expanduser)
        """
        return cls(os.path.expanduser('~'))

p = PathTest('C:/')
print(p) # 'C:/'

q = PathTest.expanduser()
print(q) # C:\Users\Username
```

Comment: I have added a rudimentary subclass which provides an `expanduser` method.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Use `pathlib.Path.home()` per @maf88

Answer (score 129):

As of python-3.5, there is [`pathlib.Path.home()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.home), which improves the situation somewhat.

The result on Windows is

```
>>>pathlib.Path.home()
WindowsPath('C:/Users/username')
```

and on Linux

```
>>>pathlib.Path.home()
PosixPath('/home/username')
```

Comment: What about a different user's home directory? (e.g. not *your* home dir)

Comment: @user9074332 -- how about `Path('~username').expanduser()`?  There's also `os.path.expanduser('~username')`, but pay close attention to how each of these fails if the user does not exist!

Answer (score 42):

There is [method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.expanduser) `expanduser()`:

```
p = PosixPath('~/films/Monty Python')
p.expanduser()
# => PosixPath('/home/eric/films/Monty Python')
```

Comment: This is the best answer for cases where we need to work with paths that contain a tilde /`~` prefix.

Answer (score 9):

For people who are lazy to read [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947427/getting-home-directory-with-pathlib#) :

Now there is the `pathlib.Path.home` method.

Comment: Thank you for converting a comment to an answer. You did the right thing. People who don't read comments aren't lazy, by the way. Answers belong in answer posts. Those comments have been deleted now.

Answer (score -3):

**Caveat**: This answer is 3.4 specific. As pointed out in other answers, this functionality was added in later versions.

It looks like there is no better way to do it. I just searched [the documentation](https://pathlib.readthedocs.org/en/pep428/) and nothing relevant came up for my search terms.

- `~` has zero hits
- `expand` has zero hits
- `user` has 1 hit as a return value for `Path.owner()`
- `relative` has 8 hits, mostly related to `PurePath.relative_to()`