# How can I create a directory on Linux with Python when the base path should include ~/?

Tags: python, linux, mkdir, pathlib, home-directory

I would like to use Python to create a directory on Linux (i.e. `~/mydir/`). I tried this...

```py
from pathlib import Path
Path('~/mydir/').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

...but this creates the directory here:

```
/script-location/~/mydir/
```

What I really want is `mydir` to be created in the user's home directory:

```
~/mydir/
```

How can I do this without querying the user's login name?

Comment: `~` is expanded by the shell. It has no special meaning elsewhere.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, you could use environment variables like `$USER` etc., but why not query the username?

Comment: See answers here: [how-to-find-the-real-user-home-directory-using-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668909/how-to-find-the-real-user-home-directory-using-python) and here: [getting-home-directory-with-pathlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947427/getting-home-directory-with-pathlib)

Comment: @Marco it is entirely possible using `os.path.expanduser()`